# Deploying war file in Tomcat webapps directory is not running on browser

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have made a project in Eclipse. It is running on local tomcat server. But when I deploy this war file in external tomcat server webapps directory. It is deploying correctly but when run on browser, Page not found. But I checked that directory and pages exists there but tomcat says Page not found. Then I made a demo.txt file inside project directory but it is also not found by tomcat. Now, I created a directory inside tomcat Webapps. It is found but my Project directory not found which exists there. What should I do now?

Comment: Check context root of deployed application

Comment: Is your browser telling you it can't load your page, or do you see a Tomcat error saying it can't load your page?

Answer (score -1):

Check the port number. If not 80, try 8080 then.

Answer (score -1):

There may be something wrong in web.xml or in library.

You can check tomcat Manager whether the Context is false(if then you will get only 404 error).

You can check the tomcat log files to get the exact error.